# How to build request to java server?

Tags: java, servlets

I am writing a REST server and client for it on Java. I do this for educational purpose.

My server is a web application that handle request from clients via servlet. After that it opens a storage conenction, retrieve data and send it as a json. 
My client is a web aplication which has some simple web pages. User click a button, servlet on client handle and send(sic!) request to the server.

May be this way a little bit odd because on the client side moderbn world write just html pages with rich JS code, e.g. Bootstrap, Backbone Angular etc.and server side is wrote via JAX-RS or Spring, but my aim is to write this pet project on pure java as simple as it can be.

I faced with an issue that I don't understand how to send request from client side to the server side. I have received request from user in servlet and I want to send a reponse to the server.

What are possible ways to do that and what is the best one?

Thanks.

Comment: Read documents about servlet container and ajax call.

Comment: I would like to avoid AJAX calls. Do we have another way to send request to the server?

Comment: Aren't you just in a difficult and confusing way asking how to call a REST service from a servlet? In which case the answer is: use the JAX-RS API, for example Jersey which is the reference implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to call your webservices with parameter required on server side. Update your view/jsp/html based on the data get from servlet.

Ajax Call from javascript :

```
function onButtonClick(){
   $.ajax({         
            type:       "post", //method type
            dataType:   "json", //response data type
            url:        ajaxUrl, //your webservice URL
            data:       "jsonobj", // Data to be send to server
            success:    function(response)  // call back function after get successfull responce
            {  
               // Process JSON response here  

            }  
      });    
 }
```

Your servlet code :

```
public class ResellerServlet extends HttpServlet   
{    
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  
    {  
        //Process request here   
        // Convert your response in JSON and send it back to client
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Yagnesh. As I mentioned U try to avoid using request from web page, I want to do that when servlet has been invoked

Comment: Than how can you call servlet from client side without request from web page ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question client click on web page, servlet is invoked -- client will make a request, I was misuse lang, I mean don't do ajaz requests. I assume that if I need to calculate in some way my data from server before show it, it will be better to do on java that JS

Comment: can you post some code how client will make request to servlet ?

Comment: I mean submit a post form, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160311/html-form-processing-in-java-servlet

Comment: it means that you have to process your JSON response on server side it self and create view in servlet and write it as output of servlet that will display on browser.